# Switch <li> active element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menuitem

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mudo0acs/6) is a link for a fiddle project I am working on right now. What I am trying to do is to switch active menu element depending on what section is displayed right now on screen. So if it is Kontakti on screen, then Kontakti in menu (`<!--NAV BAR-->`) has to display as active item. I am not familiar with jS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add data-role=navigate attribute to ul element where navigation is housed,
In the javascript section of this fiddle,

please try with the following code,

```
 $(function()
  {
  $("[data-role=navigate]").find("li > a").click(function()
    {
        $(this).parents("ul").find("li.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    })

  })
```

I will explain in brief what the code does...

1) Binds a click event handler to <a> inside <li> which is inside <ul> with attribute data-role=navigate

2) When the click happens, it removes the active class for the current element.

3) Assigns the active class to the immediate parent of the <a>

It is a good practice to target specific needs in JS by placing attribute in the DOM elements and hooking up event listeners using that attribute.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the issue. I am trying to change active element my scrolling through the content of page.

Comment: Sorry for not understanding your requirement properly, you can use bootstrap's scrollspy http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy for this purpose

Comment: I can't find the way to make it work... I tried to snipe on each of nav divs, but still no result

Comment: Here is the updated JS fiddle with scrollspy http://jsfiddle.net/mudo0acs/10/, take a look by scrolling through the sections

Comment: Please ignore the previous fiddle as a small error was there, please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/mudo0acs/13/. The section is skipped currently but will be activated on the navbar once it has more content. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! I would be stuck with this for ages if not your help! Appreciate!

Comment: I ran across a malfunction - after choosing particular menu item and AFTER, while scrolling, selected item remains as active. In result, there are 2 selected item - 1 selected by user, 2nd is changing by scrollspy

Comment: Can you specify exactly in which menu items you are facing problem?

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap's [Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) might be something that could be useful in this case. It highlights what part of the page is displayed on the screen on a separate sub-navigation part of the page.

Btw, if you have Bootstrap code you can display it on [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/) quite easily. It provides Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript files by default.

Comment: Could you please help me to implement Affix to my code? I am new to this sort of things and I am slightly confused...

Comment: @MarksGniteckis Hi, I created a template that uses Affix. You can use the template at http://www.bootply.com/T4nXcARH4V and apply your own content to it. Currently, the sub-navigation appears on the left-hand side of the page, but you can cut & paste it to the right hand side of the page if required. If you wanna save your changes at Bootply, then I recommend to become a new Bootply user. You just need to click 'Login' button in the top right-hand corner of the page, and enter your details and press the 'Sign up' button.

Answer (score 1):

You say you're not familiar with JavaScript but you're asking for functionality that needs JavaScript. I'd recommend trying to use a plugin if it's not something you can write yourself.

Waypoints would do exactly what you're looking for:
http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/